# How to read data from an API which gives Unauthorized error when accessing the Request URL

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to "SCRAPE" a website but when I try to open the request url it gives me Unauthorized error with 401 status.

Website: https://www.dbxkjfejjekef.com/

Request URL: https://www.db.co.in/__api__/api/1.0/feed/home

Error message:

```
{
   error: "Unauthorized",
   message: "Check failed",
   path: "/__api__/api/1.0/feed/home",
   timestamp: 1597861914142,
   status: 401
}
```

In the Preview section of the developer tools I can see the data:

[image]

How do I scrape these data so it looks like:

```
Title : slug + title
URL : shareUri
```

I can write the code but I don't know what to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the correct response, set `x-aut-web-t` HTTP header:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.divyabhaskar.co.in/__api__/api/1.0/feed/home'
headers = {
    'x-aut-web-t': '420x66695ztde3qao6a69'
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "metaTitle": "Gujarati News, News in Gujarati \u2013 \u0a97\u0ac1\u0a9c\u0ab0\u0abe\u0aa4 \u0ab8\u0aae\u0abe\u0a9a\u0abe\u0ab0 | \u0aa6\u0abf\u0ab5\u0acd\u0aaf \u0aad\u0abe\u0ab8\u0acd\u0a95\u0ab0",
    "metaDescription": "Gujarati News Samachar - Find all Gujarati News and Samachar, News in Gujarati, Gujarat News, Gujarati News Headlines and Daily Breaking News, Gujarati News Paper in DivyaBhaskar.co.in.",
    "metaKeywords": "News, Gujarati news, news in Gujarati, newspaper, Gujarati newspaper, online news, daily news, national news, India news, political news, sports news",
    "cursor": "eyJ2IjoxLCJoYXNwIjp0cnVlLCJmbWF0IjpudWxsLCJsbWF0IjoxNTk3ODQwNTc0MDAwfQ",
    "feed": [
        {
            "storyId": 127630068,
            "shareUri": "https://divya-b.in/CQ4aHWCa48",
            "priority": 1,

...and so on.
```

Comment: thank you Andrej.



It works as expected but I see weird characters when printing:
    
    "title": "\u0a9b\u0ac7\u0ab2\u0acd\u0ab2\u0abe 24 \u0a95\u0ab2\u0abe\u0a95\u0aae\u0abe\u0a82 63 \u0ab9\u0a9c\u0abe\u0ab0\u0aa5\u0ac0 \u0ab5\u0aa7\u0ac1 \u0a9f\u0ac7\u0ab8\u0acd\u0a9f, 1,145 \u0aa8\u0ab5\u0abe \u0aa6\u0ab0\u0acd\u0aa6\u0ac0 \u0a85\u0aa8\u0ac7 17\u0aa8\u0abe \u0aae\u0acb\u0aa4, \u0a95\u0ac1\u0ab2 \u0a95\u0ac7\u0ab8 82 \u0ab9\u0a9c\u0abe\u0ab0\u0aa8\u0ac7 \u0aaa\u0abe\u0ab0",

Comment: @parikhparth23 It's not weird, it's unicode representation - try to `print(data['metaTitle'])`, it should print correct unicode characters.